# How to edit configuration settings in Azure Function for Azure Gov

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-gov

I'd like to use code like this in my Azure Function:

```cs
var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionKey"];
```

Given that there's no UI for Azure Functions in the Azure Government portal yet, is there a way to add this via the Azure CLI or is there another way to make this happen?

**Update**

I figured it out:

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name appname --settings SubscriptionKey=1234 --resource-group resourcegroupname
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've already found out, you can do this via Azure CLI with the following command:

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name appname --settings SubscriptionKey=1234 --resource-group resourcegroupname
```